# junit does not appear even after adding the dependency in pow.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit

I'm learning Java with Spring boot and I can't make JUnit annotations work in my classes.

When I put **@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)** or **@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)** it doesn't even appear Cannot solve symbol as if I hadn't added the dependency in pom.xml.

My full pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fquadros</groupId>
    <artifactId>minhasfinancas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>minhasfinancas</name>
    <description>Projeto para gerenciamento de finanças pessoais</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencia para poder rodar testes feitos em Junit 4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm using the IDE: Intelij 2018.2.8

**What I've tried to do:**

After I added the dependencies I went to build / rebuild Project.

In the terminal, I already ran the `mvn clean` and `mvn install` commands.

at the time of installation I get several errors:

https://codepen.io/flavionfg/full/KKaQVbG

Do I need to do anything else to use JUnit?

Comment: From the logs, it does not appear to be a junit error,
`- Exception during pool initialization. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root" at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running `mvn clean` and then `mvn install`, try to run first `mvn clean compile` to download the dependencies and compile your project.

Another thing to mention, if you are planning to support JUnit 4 tests, you should add `junit-vintage-engine` dependency, as `junit-jupiter-engine` is for running JUnit 5 tests.

You can read a bit more here: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5

Comment: I just tried it and it worked out, thank you very much.